# Azure b2c accesstoken does not work with aZURE APIM

Tags: vue.js, jwt, azure-api-management, azure-ad-b2c

I'm facing a problem when I try to call an API from Azure APIM using the JWT validation in the inbound process here's the conf :
[APIM policy conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8PaZ.png)

accessToken retrieved from the client application :
[data retrieved from azure b2c when authentication succeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mft87.png)

when I try to call the API from Azure APIM using Postman I'm getting always this error :
[Postman call to azure APIM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2cpn.png)

Do you think I missed something explain this result please ?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JWT is predominantly used for authorization. The access token contains a hash of header and payload based on the algorithm provided in the header. You can check this using [JWT playground](https://jwt.io/).

The error might be because of the policy.  As the access token received from the server should be able authorize the api call .
Refer the following
[API Management access restriction policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies)

you can also refer this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/538259/how-to-create-or-sign-jwt-token-in-azure-apim.html).

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but I could not understand what is the missing part